# Add image to link with CSS

Tags: html, css, image, stylesheet

I have some URLs to which I want to add the same image. I've got the following code:

```
a.linkArrow
{ 
    background: transparent url('../images/abc.png') no-repeat center right;
    padding-right: 60px;
}
```

And a link example:

```
<a class="inkArrow" href="#abc">Abc?</a>
```

The problem is, the image appears on the left of the text of the link. I want that the image appears always on the right side of the text AND that the distance from the start position of the link text to the start position of the image is always the same. So when I have multiple links in a row that the images of the links align. The image should be clickable and lead to the same url as the link (I'm not sure if it is possible to enclose it in the same  tag for this approach.

Any ideas?

Comment: Without altering the HTML, I think this is only possible with scripting.  See my edited answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with jQuery too.

```
<a href="#" class="imageLink">Some Link</a>

$('.imageLink').each(function(){
   $(this).append(' <img src="YOUR IMAGE HERE">'); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/6Nc3n/

**EDIT:**

I realized that the OP also said *the distance from the **start** position of the link text to the **start** position of the image is always the same*

So I modified the code

```
var finalWidth = 0;
var getWidth;

$('.imageLink').each(function(){
    getWidth = $(this).width();      
    if(getWidth > finalWidth){
      finalWidth = getWidth;
    }
});

finalWidth +=15;

$('.imageLink').each(function(){
   var getText = $(this).text();
    $(this).html('<span style="display:inline-block; width:' + finalWidth + 'px;">' + getText + '</span>');
   $(this).append(' <img src="http://icdn.pro/images/en/l/e/left-arrow-icone-3702-32.png">');
   $(this).css('textDecoration','none'); 

});
```

What this does is get the `width` of each link text.  If checks if that `width` is the longest, if not ignores, but if yes, then makes it the `finalWidth`.  This `finalWidth` then added to a new `span` created around the text and styled with `inlineblock`.

**Updated Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/6Nc3n/2/

Answer (score 6):

it is "right center" not "center right" see example: http://jsfiddle.net/bingjie2680/ZtLCA/

it also works when you want them to be same distance between text link and image see example: http://jsfiddle.net/bingjie2680/ZtLCA/1/

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer but you missed one vital point, according to the OP the images should vertically align. distance between START point of text and start point of image is the same. You made it: distance between END point of text and start point of image is the same. Just make the `a` `display:block` or fixed width and you are there.

Comment: This is a good CSS solution but it is not correct.  The OP wants *the distance from the start position of the link text to the start position of the image is always the same* so that the images and links align.

Comment: Exactly, @bingjie2680.  That is why I provided a js solution.

Comment: @Jason, sorry, I just updated my comments. it is possible to just add the disply:block. see here:http://jsfiddle.net/bingjie2680/ZtLCA/3/

Comment: Not really.  Because you are using the `padding` to effect the change.  See what happens here with a longer link: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/ZtLCA/4/  Yes, it works, but only if you know the max size

Comment: that is happening because of the frame width. try to enlarge the right frame by dragging the border.

Comment: Yes.  True @bingjie2680.  But then you have to always adjust the `width` of the `a href`.  For instance, if you make the link text smaller, but expand the right frame, you have too much space, unless, again, you set a static `width` based on the max text.

Answer (score 1):

```
a.linkArrow
{ 
    background: transparent url('../images/abc.png') no-repeat center right;
    display:block;
    width: /* image width PLUS the distance you want from the text px */;
    height: /* image height px */;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is give them a fixed width and a `display: block`.
Your css would look like this:

```
a.linkArrow
{
  background: transparent url('../images/abc.png') no-repeat right center;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
}
```